# Editing Content on the Front End

Tags: safecracker, zoo-visitor, related-entries

I'm working on a membership site utilizing Zoo Visitor.  I have several two "member-related" channels - that either directly (Zoo Visitor) or indirectly (Firms, Resources, News, etc) relate back to the member.  Allowing the member to edit their Zoo Visitor profile on the front end is easy.  What I'm struggling with is allowing them to edit the other related content.

When my client sets up a new user, they can relate that user to a particular Firm in the Firms channel.  Right now, I'm using [DS Sub Channel](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ds-sub-channel), which is basically a relatable field-type that also let's you create and edit entries from the other channel.  For instance, when my client is setting up a new firm, they can quickly add a user to the Zoo Visitor channel right from the Firms channel, then relate that user to the firm.

What I'm mainly struggling with is how to securely let them edit the firm information that they are related to once they have logged in.  Do I need to have my client set a particular user as the author for that firm?  What if I have more than one member that is related to that firm - can any of them edit the firm information?  Am I missing something obvious, or just overthinking this?

I've been struggling with the best way to handle this but have just put it off until now.  Unfortunately, I'm to the point where I need to solve it once and for all.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: will you have multiple users per firm?
you want the user to be able to edit the related firms information?

am i understanding this correctly?

Comment: There can be multiple users per firm. It's acceptable to the client that either a single user can edit or multiple could edit (the latter probably a convenience more than anything).  Right now, there is a DS Sub (relationships) field set up for Primary Member (one) and Additional Members (multiple).  I also thought about setting up a separate Playa field for "Admin" member, thinking I might need it for this reason alone.  The idea is that the logged in user who had the permissions for Firm A could edit their contact information, locations, social media info, bio, etc. Hope that helps!

Comment: i assume you've tried the channel:form tag for editing the entry, correct? tried enclosing the channel:form tag within {if logged_in}{/if} tag pair?

Comment: I haven't done anything yet. I was really looking to see a) If it was possible, and what the best approach was, and b) what security "gotchas" I should be aware of. So it sounds like it's fine to do as long as I pass the appropriate entry_ID of the firm they have permission to edit through to my (currently) SAEF forms?

Comment: definitely possible. only thing i think that will be an issue is allowing multiple members edit the same firm entry.